# require(filePath) not working in NodeJS in ES6 with filePath as variable

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

While working with NodeJS project with mongoose for MongoDB, I used following code snippet to import all the mongoose models.

```
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file) {
    require(modelsPath + '/' + file);
});
```

This worked flawlessly.

Recently, I started working on a Rubix project. It included a nodeJs server with ES6 code (using babel).

The above code snippet for importing mongoose models does not work.
On further experimentation, I found that for `require()`, variable is not allowed. If write the file path itself in require, i.e.
`require('path/to/file')`, it works. But if I do something like

```
var filePath = 'path/to/file';
require(filePath);
```

It stopped working. There was no error. It just hung before starting server.

Am I missing anything basic from ES6?

#### edit

Following is the content of module I'm trying to import

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.models.User,
    api = {},
    auth = require('../utils/apiAuth'),
    _ = require("lodash"),
    apiResponse = require('../utils/apiResponse'),
    apiErrors = require('../utils/apiErrors'),
    config = require('../config/config'),
    bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

// ALL
api.users = function (req, res) {
  console.log('here?');
  User.find(function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
      return apiResponse.sendError(apiErrors.APPLICATION.INTERNAL_ERROR, null, 500, req, res);
    } else {
      return apiResponse.sendResponse(users, 200, req, res);
    }
  });
};

//.... other apis ....//

router.get('/users', api.users);


module.exports = router;
```

It works with all the previous projects I've worked with.
Could it have anything to do with Rubix?

Comment: Just tried a example, did work. Can you show the content of your module?

Comment: thanks @DrakaSAN for prompt reply. I've edited the question with module details.

Comment: How do you import it, I don't see anything that should error out in the module. You can also reduce the code to make a MCVE, which will prevent you from sharing huge part of code (boring for us, could be dangerous for you), it s a win win :)

Comment: @DrakaSAN yes, there is no error with code in module. I'm importing it as mentioned above  `var filePath = 'path/to/file';
require(filePath);`

Comment: @DrakaSAN Im implementing it in a Rubix project. Im haven't worked with ES6 much. And Rubix, NOT AT ALL! The code snippet I shared, I've used it in a few projects before and it works. So no issues in the module for sure. Will see if I can find anything in Rubix. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not that experienced with `express.router`, but aren't you supposed to make a `app.use('/something', yourRouter)`?

Comment: @DrakaSAN yes. I've done that after the above code snippet. Thing is, server doesn't even start. I put logs to check and code doesn't even complete 1 iteration of loop I've put in question where there is `require()` statement in it. And doesn't even crash with any error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124431/discussion-between-drakasan-and-droidboyjr).

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Too long, and would be impratical as a comment*

Here is how I tried your code. Calling `/users` do print `here?`.

main.js:

```
'use strict';

//Dependencies
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    t = './router.js';

app.use(require(t));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('?');
    res.end();
});

app.listen(2219);
```

router.js:

```
'use strict';

//Export
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    api = {};

// ALL
api.users = function (req, res) {
    console.log('here?');
    res.end();
};

//...

router.get('/users', api.users);

//...

module.exports = router;
```